# Neon Glow for Html element is not working well on Mobile

Tags: html, css

I want to make these spans glow and I have succeed in Desktop and its very nice, but when opening the website on mobile, the glow is appearing too small and it needs a magnifier in order to been seen...I tried to increase the px but no change.

```css
@keyframes glowing {
  0% { box-shadow: 0 0 -10px rgb(196, 196, 196);}
  40% { box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgb(196, 196, 196); }
  60% { box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgb(196, 196, 196); }
  100% { box-shadow: 0 0 -10px rgb(196, 196, 196); }
}

.glowButton {
  animation: glowing 1000ms infinite;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(133, 133, 133);
}
```

```html
<div class="glowButton">Button</div>
```

Comment: Have you added any `viewport` meta tags to your HTML?

Comment: yess...I have this 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">